# Safe to Mutate State Object Directly in useEffect? (React & Immutability)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets init a state, giving object as initial state. To update any property of the object, we usually clone state and re-set using setter.

But in following example, without any setter, I can update properties of that object and they are reflected on the dom without any complain.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [x, setX] = useState({test: 0}) // setter is never used
  const [y, setY] = useState(0)

  useEffect(()=>{
    // This may not be suitable for production code
    x.test = x.test + 1
  }, [y])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>x = {x.test}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setY(y+1)}>Increase</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I assume this behavior is related to the mutable nature of objects in JavaScript.

Question is, can this code lead to any adverse effects?

Also, this can be produced only inside a `useEffect` hook. if I changed my code as

```
<button onClick={() => x.test = x.test + 1}>Increase</button>
```

this will no longer works. Why there is a difference, if we mutate the same object?

Comment: *"can this code lead to any adverse effects?"* - Maybe.  Look at it another way... Since this behavior is explicitly not recommended by the vendor, unless someone can conclusively prove that it **can't** lead to any adverse effects, why rely on it at all?

Comment: Why not use `ref` instead if you don't plan to use the setter anyway?

Comment: I agree this is a deviation from standard and agreed practices, but I believe the understanding of peculiar behaviors come handy when you are working on complex solutions.

Comment: Changing `x` in the click handler works as well. You just don't call any `useState`'s setter  so the component never rerenders. The whole idea about state is that it rerenders the component when changed using the setter. If mutated, it doesn't trigger the render. In the `useEffect` example you call `y` setter so render js triggered correctly.

Comment: @Konrad That's true, if we add another trigger to re-render DOM, that reflects the updated value for `x.test` also. So, i that case, setState is a re-render trigger behind the scene. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's why state should be really only used when you want to rerender the component. In every other case, ref can be used

Comment: Would you like to compose an answer, explaining this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not violate the rules stated by the React documentation, because React (when used as intended) makes certain guarantees on how it will behave.

React doesn't make guarantees on how it would behave if used differently.

The internal implementation of React may change fundamentally without notice. React will keep their guarantees, but the actual behavior when used outside of the rules may change completely.

#### About your example

If you use a `useState` but never call its `setState`, the value behaves effectively in the same way as if you would use a `useRef`.

But ...

1. Your `x`, including the manually changed property, would be overwritten as soon as `setX` is called.
2. Your changed `x` would never be displayed, if not something else (e.g. the change of your `y`) triggers a re-render (that's why your `onClick` version doesn't work). This introduces an unwanted dependency between unrelated things.
3. You are not following the rules and standards, so other people may be confused by your code.

Your `onClick` handler effects the `x` in the same as the `useEffect`, the difference is, that the `y` is not changed, so there is no reason for React to re-render. Try to call `setY` after changing the `x`, and the new value of `x` should also become visible.

#### Conclusion

That said, you basically have the exact behavior as with a `useRef`, so you should use a `useRef` if you want this behavior. If you use `useState`, you should use it as intended.